# DevOps manual change handling

Tags: devopscenter

I am implementing DevOps Centre as a move away from change sets but am struggling to find information on what seems like a fairly straight forward question. I am happy with multiple projects looking to the single repo to allow for different pipelines however how does it handle admins making manual changes to production during development that may impact deployment? Obviously ideally this would never happen but often we work with third parties who will wish to make changes as they please.

Comment: Changes directly in production are bad practice and an anti-pattern. The only reason this should ever happen is in response to a severity 1 issue - one that prevents business operation without workaround- and even then it should still, ideally, start on a lower org with rapid verification and promotion to production. Personally I would say the third parties doing this should have permissions removed from them for jeopardising production quality and stability.